# javamail email not send

Tags: java, email, smtp, jakarta-mail, send

Im trying to send email by using javamail but im new to this theme. So far i dont get compile errors nor run errors, but the email is never send. Im using a helper class for sending an email with a local SMTP server(MailUtilLocal.java) and a servlet that sends an email(EmailServlet). Here is the code:

`
//EmailServlet.java:

```
import Beans.Usuario;
import IOBD.InputOutputBD;
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import Servlets.MailUtilLocal;
import java.util.*;

public class EmailServlet extends HttpServlet {

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    // get parameters from the request
    String userId = request.getParameter("userId");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");
    String nombre = request.getParameter("nombre");
    String tipo = request.getParameter("tipo");
    String emailAddress = request.getParameter("emailAddress");
 // create the User object and write it to a file
    Usuario user = new Usuario(userId, password, nombre, tipo, emailAddress);
    ServletContext sc = getServletContext();

 // store the User object in the session
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    session.setAttribute("user", user);


 // send email to user
    String to = emailAddress;
    String from = "email_list@murach.com";
    String subject = "Welcome to our email list";
    String body = "Dear " + nombre + ",\n\n"
            + "Thanks for joining our email list. "
            + "We'll make sure to send you announcements "
            + "about new products and promotions.\n"
            + "Have a great day and thanks again!\n\n"
            + "Kelly Slivkoff\n" + "Mike Murach & Associates";
    boolean isBodyHTML = false;
    try {
        MailUtilLocal.sendMail(to, from, subject, body, isBodyHTML);
    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        String errorMessage =
                "ERROR: Unable to send email. "
                + "Check Tomcat logs for details.<br>"
                + "NOTE: You may need to configure your "
                + "system as described in chapter 15.<br>"
                + "ERROR MESSAGE: " + e.getMessage();
        request.setAttribute("errorMessage", errorMessage);
        this.log("Unable to send email. \n"
                + "Here is the email you tried to send: \n"
                + "=====================================\n"
                + "TO: " + emailAddress + "\n"
                + "FROM: " + from + "\n"
                + "SUBJECT: " + subject + "\n"
                + "\n"
                + body + "\n\n");


    }
    // forward request and response to JSP page
    String url = "/index.jsp";
    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(url);
    dispatcher.forward(request, response);
}
}
```

//MailUtilLocal.java:

```
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;

public class MailUtilLocal {

public static void sendMail(String to, String from, String subject, String body,   boolean bodyIsHTML)
        throws MessagingException {
    // 1 - get a mail session
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "localhost");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", 25);
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);
    session.setDebug(true);
    // 2 - create a message
    Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
    message.setSubject(subject);
    if (bodyIsHTML) {
        message.setContent(body, "text/html");
    } else {
        message.setText(body);
    }
    // 3 - address the message
    Address fromAddress = new InternetAddress(from);
    Address toAddress = new InternetAddress(to);
    message.setFrom(fromAddress);
    message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddress);
    // 4 - send the message
    Transport.send(message);
}
}
```

I deleted these two lines because i get an error for not having the method addRecord on the UserIO and i dont know what should be in it

```
String path = sc.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/EmailList.txt");
UserIO.addRecord(user, path);
```

Comment: You should use a helper library like [common email](http://commons.apache.org/email/) or [spring email](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mail.html) instead of writing the boilerplate code. Secondly, you are not catching all exceptions, may be there is one that's going unnoticed.

Comment: Why did you specify **localhost** in this line of code `props.put("mail.smtp.host", "localhost");`. You need to specify a particular mail server here.

Comment: @Lion OP mentioned it was a local mail server.

Comment: Oh I was just sleepy to read that!

Comment: The JavaMail FAQ has some debugging tips.

Comment: Don´t you need to auth. with the smtp server in some way? Hm otherwise, maybe it is a problem with the mail-server config or a firewall issue...or maybe the parameters email-adress etc, are not right...spaces, strange encoding? Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

What sometimes happen when you're using a local smtp server is that your ISP will block port 25, so that your SMTP server cannot communicate with the remote server.

What you can do in that case is use a different port to send email from your smtp server, or use a third party service that accepts connections from ports other than 25, commonly 587 and 465.

Have a look at [Sendgrid](http://sendgrid.com), [mailjet](http://mailjet.com) and [postmarkapp](http://postmarkapp.com), as they are some of the best known providers